# How to increase default fetchsize for queries (Oracle DB)

Tags: oracle, database-connection, ormlite

How can I set the fetchsize for an Oracle database? For example, when starting SQL*Plus, I can `set arraysize 250` and increase the performance of my queries drastically. How can I achieve the same with ORMLite?

The only thing I found to do this programmatically is the method `void setDefaultRowPrefetch(int var1) throws SQLException;` in `oracle.jbdc.OracleConnection`, but this has nothing to do ORMLite. So, how can I access the underlying connection and set database specific parameters, such as *arraysize* for Oracle DB's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The only thing I found to do this programmatically is the method void `setDefaultRowPrefetch(int var1)` throws SQLException; in `oracle.jbdc.OracleConnection`, but this has nothing to do ORMLite. So, how can I access the underlying connection and set database specific parameters, such as arraysize for Oracle DB's?

Unfortunately, right now this is a bit of a hack.

When running with JDBC, the `DatabaseConnection` that you get from the `JdbcConnectionSource` is actually `JdbcDatabaseConnection`.  This connection has a public `getInternalConnection()` method which returns the underlying `java.sql.Connection` (see [the source](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-jdbc/blob/608be00d59962e242b986b88fc8641ef85514009/src/main/java/com/j256/ormlite/jdbc/JdbcDatabaseConnection.java#L283)).  That should be (hopefully) a `oracle.jbdc.OracleConnection`.

I've made the change to the source to official expose that method (renamed to `getUnderlyingConnection()`) which will be in version 5.3 of ORMLite.  See the [pull-request](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/commit/0da89139c12c2b8225503334250311f51677d1d2).